# React-Native need airplay and chrome cast feature

Tags: react-native, chromecast, airplay

I'm eager to know is there any way to integrate `google's chrome cast` and `apple's airplay` in react native app ?

Answer (score 1):

After researching a lot on internet, I found this [library](https://github.com/charliesbox/react-native-google-cast) is worth. It has both SDKs included in its core components with great examples.

Comment: Did you try it? It look like many issues and with no support!!!! Plus does it work with smart tv with chrome cast device?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't use

Comment: Any alternative approach you come up with? Or you just gave up :D

Comment: I think, only best way is to use the native official sdk and add a module to react native by bridging to java-script code. what u say?

Comment: That project didn't come :)